# Vertically align div with text on the same line

Tags: html, css

I have a text and a div next to each other (where it says "BitHumor" and the "check" symbol) But they are not aligned with each other (see the image)

Here's my HTML and CSS codes:

```
<font face='HelveticaNeue-bold' color='#4671A5' font size='6' style='position:absolute;z-index:500;width:100%;top:120px;vertical-align:middle;'>
<center>" . $row["username"]. "&nbsp;<div class='" . $row["status"]. "'></div>   
    <style>
    .official {
    content: url('http://bithumor.co/1234567890.png');
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
      display: inline;
    z-index:999999;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align:middle;
    }
    </style>
```

[image]

**How do I make the text ("BitHumor") and the div (image - with checkmark) vertically aligned?**

Comment: Have you tried applying `vertical-align: bottom` to the checkmark? Also, can you post the full HTML & CSS, so the problem can be reproduced? Or post a demo at jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I have not tried that but I will not and that is the entire HTML for the text and checkmark image

Comment: Vertical-align: bottom doesn't work

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the code you've provided. Is there anywhere to view the live site?

Comment: Yes - http://server.bithumor.co/profile/index1.php?id=953 -  I will also provide the full source code of the ENTIRE webpage in a jsbin

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZB9vnkHg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two options:

1. *Remove the absolute positioning.* By removing `position: absolute` from the checkmark class (`.official`), you can then use [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#Syntax).
2. *Use `margin` for alignment.* Add this to the checkmark class: `.official { margin-top: 5px; }`